# Active Cell's Row & Column Highlighting in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, highlight

[image: Highlight Active Row & Column]

I am looking for a way to highlight the entire row and column in a google sheet depending on the active cell.

What is the best possible way to accomplish this task.

Comment: Using Google Apps Script and the Sheets API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your showing sample demonstration, I remembered [this post (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/06/11/highlighting-row-and-column-of-selected-cell-using-google-apps-script/). In this case, I think that your goal can be achieved using `onSelectionChange`. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, save the script. And, just in case, please reopen the Spreadsheet.

```js
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const maxRows = sheet.getMaxRows();
  const maxColumns = sheet.getMaxColumns();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, maxRows, maxColumns).setBackground(null);
  sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, maxColumns).setBackground("#e6b8af");
  sheet.getRange(1, range.getColumn(), maxRows, 1).setBackground("#c9daf8");
}
```

#### Testing:

When the above script is used, the following situation is obtained.

[image]

#### Reference:

- [onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee)